# Outlook collapses IMAP folders by default

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, imap

I recently switched my mail account from POP3 to IMAP and created server-side rules to help me manage my mail better.

I use Outlook 2007 as a mail client.

For some reason, it seems that ever since I switched to IMAP, all my folders are collapsed by default. Since my folder tree goes down 4 levels, this is pretty annoying. I don't know any better than Outlook remembering my folder preferences, but it seems to forget them as soon as I close the program now.

**Is there any cause for this, and more importantly, is there a known fix for this problem?**

Comment: Seems like you're not the only one having the problem (I know that this is 2003) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/omars/archive/2004/12/24/331592.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Finally, I found the solution to this...

There is NO WAY to remove the Personal Folders when using IMAP, but to make the IMAP Inbox folder load by default when opening Outlook 2007.... just do as follows:

- On the **Tools menu**, choose **Options**.
- Click the **Other tab**, and choose **Advanced Options**.
- Under **General Settings**, next to the Startup in this folder box, click **Browse**.
- In the Select Folder dialog box, **select the IMAP Inbox folder**.
- **Click OK** to close the Select Folder window. **Click OK** to close the Advanced Options window and close the Options window.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
[Dan Root](http://www.danroot.net)
Root Worldwide, Inc.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, while Outlook is a great program and is therefore arguably considered the top standard when it comes to business email, it has a lot of "gotchas". This just happens to be one of them, and it has caused my clients a right lot of pain, too.

> Outlook 2010 is supposed to remember which folders were expanded when it is closed. Unfortunately, IMAP accounts don't conform to this.
>
> [windowssecrets.com](http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/152776-Folders-keep-collapsing?p=895567&viewfull=1#post895567)

As a result, I'm going to suggest that my client moves to Exchange 365 mail, as I believe a Microsoft Exchange email account under Outlook preserves the state of the account's folder hierarchy upon closing the application.