# Outlook 2007 IMAP removes the ability to create date flags?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, imap

I am currently trying out IMAP vs POP3 (which I have used so far), but notice some strange quicks in Outlook 2007 that really make me reconsider.

Apart from the fact that all my folders now [collapse by default every time I start Outlook](https://superuser.com/questions/153531/outlook-collapses-imap-folders-by-default), I have now also **lost the ability to link a date to a flag**. I can only mark an e-mail as flagged, but it will be categorized in the 'No date' section. I have completely lost the Today/Tomorrow/This Week/Someday features that I have grown to love in Outlook.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to restore this functionality?

**UPDATE:** I am now running Outlook 2010, but it has the same behaviour. I am guessing it is by design, but it still feels like quite a step backward to me. Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation of the IMAP protocol. Flagging e-mail with a date is a feature of Outlook.

The only solution (as far as I know) is to use POP3.

Comment: It blows my mind that Outlook does not have the ability to use local storage for these flags when using IMAP. Flagging e-mail with a date is a brilliant feature, and this pretty much counters all the benefits offered by IMAP :/